# Please help me on this hard questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

> Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \times \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and define $R$ on $A$ by $(X_1,Y_1)R(X_2,Y_2)$ if $X_1+Y_1 = X_2+Y_2$.
>
> (a) Verify that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$
>
> (b) Determine the equivalence classes $[(1,3)], [(2,4)],$ and $ [(1,1)]$
>
> (c) Determine the partition induced by $R$

I don't understand how can I prove the equivalence relation on (a)
Please help

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use a title actually describing your problem

Comment: An equivalence relation must satisfy three conditions. Have you been able to prove any of them yet?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?  What do you know about what an equivalence relation is?  People will be able to give you appropriate help if you edit your question to provide that kind of information.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more advice.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: For (b) and (c) do you know the definitions of equivalence class and induced partition? For example, are (1,2) and (2,3) in the same equivalence class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first try to figure out what the relationship means.

What does $(a,b)$ being related to $(c,d)$ means.  Is $(2,4)$ related to $(1,2)$? If not what *is* related to $(2,4)$

So $(a,b)$ being related to $(c,d)$ means $a+b = c+d$.  And $(2,4)$ being related to $(1,2)$ would mean that $2+4 = 1+2$ which isn't true so $(2,4)$ is not related to $(1,2)$.  So what is related to $(2,4)$.  Well, $(2,4)$ is related to $(c,d)$ if $2+4=6= c+d$ so $(2,4)$ is related to $(c,d)$ if $c+d = 6$ so $(2,4)$ is related to $(1,5)$ and $(2,4)$ and $(3,3)$ and $(4,2)$ and $(5,1)$.

You should do all that *before* you start trying to do the question.

Then....

Go through the three conditions for equivalency.

1) is $R$ reflexive?  Is it true that for any $(a,b)$ that $(a,b)$ $R$ $(a,b)$.  Well, that's true if $a+b$ always equals $a+b$ and false if it doesn't always equal.  As $a+b = a+b$ always, $R$ is relflexive.

2) is $R$ symmetric?  Is it true that if $(a,b)\ R\ (c,d)$ then it must be true that $(c,d)\ R\ (a,b)$?  Well, that's true if whenever $a+b = c+d$ that it must be true that $c+d =a+b$.  Equality is equality and you can switch the order.

3) is $R$ transitive? Is it true that $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(e,f)$ that it must be true that $(a,b)R(c,d)$?  Well that's true if whenever you have $a+b = c+d$ and $c+d=e+f$ then you must have $a+b = e+f$.  Well, equality is equality and equality is transitive.

In general this is a relation based on view if sums are equal and equality is the most basic of equavalence relations so...

As a bonus to get you familiar with the idea of equivalence relations, hear are all $25$ elements of $A\times A$ listed into equivalence classes.  Two pairs are equivalent if and only if the fall in the same class.

Class 1: Those that add to $2$:   $\{(1,1)\}$.  $(1,1)$ is only related to itself.

Class 2: Those that add to $3$: $\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 3: Those that add to $4$: $\{(1,3), (2,2),(3,1)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 4: Those that add to $5$: $\{(1,4), (2,3),(3,2),(4,1)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 5: Those that add to $6$: $\{(1,5), (2,4),(3,3),(4,2), (5,1)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 6: Those that add to $7$: $\{(2,5), (3,4),(4,3),(5,2)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 7: Those that add to $8$: $\{(3,5), (4,4),(5,3)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 8: Those that add to $9$: $\{(4,5), (5,4)\}$. Those in this class are all related to each other.

Class 9: Those that add to $10$:   $\{(5,5)\}$.  $(5,5)$ is only related to itself.

So question b) is $[(1,3)]$ means the class of all the pairs that are reelated to $(1,3)$.  Which of the above classes is that.

And question c) is... well, reread your text to see what that means and see if it makes sense now.

Comment: I am not an English speaker so, I don't get what partition induced means

Comment: Thanks for the explanation by the way, it is crystal clear!